# How do I create a simple table in R using for loops?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, using

I was asked to create a table with three columns, A, B and C and eight rows. Column A must go 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2. Column B must alternate 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2. And column C must go 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2. I am able to produce the A column data fine, but don't know how to get B or C. This is the code I have so far:

```
dataSheet <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 3)  
colnames(dataSheet) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')  
A <- 1 
B <- 1 
C <- 1 

for (A in 1:4){
A=1
dataSheet <- rbind(dataSheet, c(A, B, C)) 
}
for (A in 5:8){
A=2
dataSheet <- rbind(dataSheet, c(A, B, C)) 
}
```

Comment: This would be a good place to use `c()` and `rep()`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/rep

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use those functions, as the professor strictly limited us to for loops. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good excuse to get familiar with the `rep()` function as it easily supports this question, but many more complicated questions if you're clever enough:

```r
dt <- data.frame(A = rep(1:2, each = 4),
                 B = rep(1:2, times = 4),
                 C = rep(1:2, each = 2))
dt
#>   A B C
#> 1 1 1 1
#> 2 1 2 1
#> 3 1 1 2
#> 4 1 2 2
#> 5 2 1 1
#> 6 2 2 1
#> 7 2 1 2
#> 8 2 2 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use that function, as the professor strictly limited us to for loops. Any advice?

Comment: @KyleCarey - I can only assume there's some larger pedagogical reason behind your homework assignment that probably shouldn't be undermined by giving you answers verbatim...my answer above is what I would do in a professional work environment for the task at hand. Good luck with the homework.

Comment: Fair enough. Although, I have 5 of these tables to do, but only asked for the answer to one of them to use as a guide since my professor didn't give us one. I also want to learn :^)

Comment: @KyleCarey - sounds good. Not trying to be judgmental or critical, just wanting to make sure you get full value for whatever you're paying for class :). Coding is inherently iterative...start with baby building blocks, stack them together one by one, and eventually you'll have code that does something useful. You've got plenty of good building blocks in this answer so far to build off of!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `R`'s vectorization for this task, i.e.

```
A <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
B <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2) # or rep(1:2, 4)
C <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2)
cbind(A,B,C)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use that function, as the professor strictly limited us to for loops. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of the following will be acceptable by your professor.

```
for (i in 1:8){
  A <- if(i <= 4) 1 else 2
  B <- if(i %% 2) 1 else 2
  C <- if(any(i %% 4 == c(0, 1, 4, 5))) 1 else 2
  dataSheet <- rbind(dataSheet, c(A, B, C)) 
}

dataSheet
#     A B C
#[1,] 1 1 1
#[2,] 1 2 2
#[3,] 1 1 2
#[4,] 1 2 1
#[5,] 2 1 1
#[6,] 2 2 2
#[7,] 2 1 2
#[8,] 2 2 1
```

Comment: This is great! How do i fix C so that it starts "1, 1" instead of "1, 2"?